# Killing a task in Ansible

Tags: ansible

What is the best way to kill a task with ansible? I have kafka running as regular executable, not as a service. When I send a kill to it, it takes a while to wrap things up and close down. I would like ansible to wait around before moving on after it sends the kill command to make sure that the service is actually stopped.

So far this is what I have, I am not sure how to do this reliably.

```
---
- name: Stopping Kafka
  command: "bin/kafka-server-stop.sh config/server.properties"
  args:
    chdir: "{{base_apps}}/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1" 
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe try putting "nohup bin/kafka-server-stop.sh config/server.properties"

Comment: wouldn't that just kick out right away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can probably solved with the [wait_for](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/wait_for_module.html) module.

With the `wait_for` module it is possible to do something like this:

```
---
- name: Stopping Kafka
  command: "bin/kafka-server-stop.sh config/server.properties"
  args:
   chdir: "{{base_apps}}/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1" 
  ignore_errors: yes

# wait until the lock file is removed
- wait_for: path=/var/lock/kafka.lock state=absent
```

This way Ansible will go on with the play only after the lock file has been removed. `wait_for` module offers some other conditions to check for, take a look at the module documentation.